# Can't add object to existing array (useState react native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have **addText()** that runs on **click** event

```
const [list, setList] = useState([])
const [value, setValue] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
    getObjectItem("tasks")
        .then(t => setList(t.item))
        .catch(e => { console.log(e) })
}), []
// A function that add data to the list array

function addText(text) {
    console.log(list);
    if (value !== "") {
        setList(prev =>
            [...prev,
            { text: text, isSelected: false }] // Adding a JS Object

        )
        setObjectItem("tasks", list);
        setValue("")
    } else {
        alert("Please type in something!")
    }
}
```

Output from **console.log(list)**:

```
  Array [
          Object {
            "isSelected": true,
            "text": "Test",
          }
        ]
```

**getObjectItem("tasks")** function:

```
const getObjectItem = async (name) => {
  try {
    const jsonItem = await AsyncStorage.getItem(name)
    const item = JSON.parse(jsonItem)
    return {
      status: 'success',
      name: name,
      item: item
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      status: 'error',
      name: name,
      error: err
    }
  }
}
```

Why can't I add values to the existing `list` array with `setList()` in **addText()** function?

Comment: Try replacing `.then(t => setList(t.item))` with `.then(t => setList([t.item]))`

Comment: It's not clear that you can't, although `setList(t.item)` seems suspicious. W/o more context it'll be difficult to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting state is asynchronous.

In `addText` you write:

```js
setObjectItem("task", list)
```

which will set the value in `AsyncStorage` to whatever `list` *was*, not what it *will* be after the state has been updated. The *easiest* solution is to create the new array then set it to state *and* `AsyncStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

> .then(t => setList([t.item]))

instead of what you wrote

Comment: `Array [
  Array [
    Array [
      Array [
        Object {
          "isSelected": true,
          "text": "Test",
        },
        Object {
          "isSelected": false,
          "text": "Test123",
        },
        Object {
          "isSelected": true,
          "text": "Test123",
        },
      ],
    ],
  ],
]`

Output After replacing .then function. Now its possible to add more arrays but it will add an array inside of an array

Comment: @FilipHuhta That's illegible. We don't know what's in AsyncStorage (is it an array? an object? a string?) so can't advise. If it's *always* an array then the original code should be fine (but it should be named `tasks`, not `task`). It's *more* likely that you're setting `task` back to `list` before the state has been updated: setting state is asynchronous.